# Export Data To Excel Without A Gridview But only on Button Click (MVC)

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to 'Export Data to Excel' on the click of a button without using Gridview in ASP.NET MVC. The page doesnt have the gridview, but i need only a button on clicking the excel file is generated by specifying the SQL View Name

Comment: Share some more information and code so easy to understand your problem

Comment: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-data-from-SQL-Server-to-Excel-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: Thank You!!! Your Answer worked!!! God Bless You!!!

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is in our controller, to query that view using your preferred data access method (ado.net, EF, etc) and manualy write the .xlsx with some open source library.

Try excel writer (https://sourceforge.net/projects/excel-writer/).

Given that you haven't given much details I'm sure at which part of the above you are stuck at.